# Do HR people get help from a technical colleague when screening CVs for technical job applications?

Tags: human-resources

I got a screening call from HR and she sounded she doesn't know anything about the job description.
I doubt she understood my cover letter either. But since she called me what does that mean? Does it mean they just look at the keywords?
Or do they cooperate with others who know about the role?

Comment: Depends on the company.

Comment: HR is not the hiring manager's friend either.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere The point is I am not even called when the job description is much more relevant. So based on what they call? Definitely not the resume and your match to the job. So HR is really running many lives I started to think..

Answer (score 10):

The overly-generic answer is: most companies use HR as a first line of filtering to remove two sorts of resumes:

- Resumes from people clearly not qualified for the job; no sense in scheduling an interview with Bob-the-Dude-Who-Just-Learned-VBScript-Yesterday for a Mid-Level .NET position.
- Resumes from people the company really doesn't want to be hiring regardless of qualifications.  It doesn't matter if Giggly "The Groper" McPsycho knows .NET inside and out, the company's not going to want them on board.

So it makes sense that you'd be talking to an HR person that might not know all the technical details about the job itself.  The HR person's mostly just needing to verify that you're worth the company's time for an interview and that you're not someone they want to turn down for non-technical reasons.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends. Normally HR tries to understand what the position is about generally, but of course they aren't in a position to assess technical competences apart from maybe very general things ("Have you worked with Azure?").

They also tend to focus on the "cultural fit" and similar too much vs technical skills. (Both are important, but obviously I can't hire someone just because they are friendly and have a great attitude if they are lacking skills).

I've already had situations that HR forwarded some applications to me since they included the core technologies. Then I discovered I didn't understand one sentence of the CV - the person clearly used google translate and I couldn't even say what the person did with the technologies.

Comment: "Very capable of capturing applications in various languages ​​at all development dais, pleasing to working with others"

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter, I once had an interview with a candidate and the HR lady who had done the screening was also here. We weren't searching for a very senior person, but sb with solid basics. In the first 10 mins it became clear the guy would reply to every a bit technical question in the vein of "I don't know but I'm eager to learn! I would love to learn that!". Debrief after the meeting: HR lady tells me she loves the candidate since he has a great attitude and, after my statement that unfortunately I need someone with skills, not just attitude, accuses me of not focusing on the right aspects.

Comment: Actually, I'd rather deal with someone with a good attitude with fair or even poor skills than an insufferable genius.  I can train people and get them up to speed, but I don't want to catch a charge for introducing an annoying coworker to the quick way down a flight of stairs.

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter, sure, but the question is how we define a good attitude. In my opinion a good attitude is: "I'm interested in A, there's plenty of materials online on A, so I sit down, spend a few days with it and learn the basics". Just stressing "I love to learn" doesn't prove anything if it's unsupported by facts. Actually it strikes me as so naive it's irritating.

Comment: Indeed. "I'm a fast learner!" Weird, because in the past several-decades of your life you've not learned any of the skills you'd need for this job. Anyway, who ever went to a job interview and said "I'm really slow at learning and struggle to pick up new skills"?

Comment: @BigMadAndy "good attitude" is job specific.  One guy I interviewed couldn't answer a single question I gave him, but he said he'd look it up or ask to every question.  I worked for a newspaper at the time, and any screwups were immortalized in print.  For that position, "NO BS" was the right attitude.

Comment: I helped interview a guy for a senior engineer/systems admin position. He was taking a year off from theological college, had no qualifications or experience but loved using the internet on his computer and was a fast learner with God on his side. To this day I have no idea how he got through HR to an interview.

Comment: @Kilisi, the guy had GOD on his side and that wasn't enough for you? They say companies tend to have unrealistic expectations but you took that to the next level ;)

Comment: @BigMadAndy he wasn't catholic, so he doesn't count ;)

Comment: @Kilisi I often refer to GOD when working on computers, usually there's another word involved though.

Answer (score 1):

Depends, as commented. I've seen the whole range from

1. a multi-disciplinanary team commenting on the resume, weightings responses, adjusting for biases, removing outliers and making a recommendation to go forward or not

To

2. Bob looking at resume and saying: yeah it lists Excel, let's call this candidate.

Comment: And Bob was HR?

Comment: @guest a colleague who worked in HR told me it stands for Hardly Relevant.

Comment: This guy created an entire reporting system using nothing but Access and Excel. It looks like he has the skills we need. /s